# Is it possible to add categories for logger without modification of standalone.xml in JBoss7?

Tags: logging, log4j, jboss7.x

According to https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/How+To I add categories for logger using the following command:
`sh /usr/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/bin/jboss-cli.sh -c --commands="/subsystem=logging/logger=com.newcategory:add(level=INFO)"`

The command modifies standalone.xml.
Is it possible to add categories for logger without modification of standalone.xml in JBoss7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no. You can with the `--read-only-server-config` in EAP 6 or WildFly, but with JBoss AS 7.1.x there is no way.

Though if it doesn't write to the configuration file then the next time it boots the category wouldn't be configured.